# Why has mongo ascending/descending sorting order flipped for a Date field?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Mongo version: 2.6.0

I am not sure I understand this. It looks like mongo DB sort order has flipped for one of my fields somehow?

Here is ASCENDING order sort:

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"time": 1}).sort({"time": 1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367e87fb820307109000cdc"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T19:37:25Z")
}
```

and DESCENDING order sort:

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"time": 1}).sort({"time": -1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53607a5bb820301547000242"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-04-30T04:21:31Z")
}
```

This flipping is happening only for `time` field.

If I sort on another field, it works fine:

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"lid": 1}).sort({"lid": 1}).limit(1).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5363f859b820306ca20002aa"), "lid" : 55960 }
> db.clicks.find({}, {"lid": 1}).sort({"lid": -1}).limit(1).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5364488bb8203071090002db"), "lid" : 2074671 }
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Looks like something strange is going on, since fetching more results is giving a totally random order.

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"time": 1}).sort({"time": 1}).limit(5).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367e87fb820307109000cdc"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T19:37:25Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53618d7eb820306ca200002e"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-04-30T23:55:30Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53675870b820307109000876"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T09:22:48Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53642974b820307109000072"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-02T23:25:20Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("535e6a11b8203015470000e5"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-04-28T14:47:25Z")
}
```

`time` is an indexed field (and used for TTL):

```js
> db.clicks.getIndexes()
[
    ...
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "time" : 1
                },
                "name" : "time_1",
                "ns" : "raw.clicks",
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 7776000
        }
]
```

UPDATE 2: I deleted the index and rebuilt it.

```js
> db.clicks.dropIndex({"time": 1})
{ "nIndexesWas" : 10, "ok" : 1 }
> db.clicks.ensureIndex({"time": 1}, {"expireAfterSeconds" : 7776000})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 9,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 10,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Still the random ordering was happening.

Then I deleted all the documents from the collection:

```js
> db.clicks.remove({})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 130 })
```

and added new documents and reran the query:

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"time": 1}).sort({"time": 1}).limit(5).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367f9a2b820307109000f2e"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T20:50:36Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367f9ccb820307109000f6f"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T20:51:04Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367f9b7b820307109000f3d"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T20:50:54Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367f9b7b820307109000f3e"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T20:50:58Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5367f9b7b820307109000f3f"),
        "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T20:51:00Z")
}
```

Still having the same problem. Is it because the index on time field is a TTL index?

UPDATE 3: Ok, so there is something wrong on this specific mongo server which I cannot quite figure out. I ran the queries on another mongo server and the queries are working fine (collection and indexes are the same):

```js
> db.clicks.find({}, {"_id": 0, "time": 1}).sort({"time": 1}).limit(10).pretty()
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:57Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:57Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:58Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:59Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:59Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:04:59Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:05:03Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:05:09Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:05:10Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-04-25T23:05:10Z") }

> db.clicks.find({}, {"_id": 0, "time": 1}).sort({"time": -1}).limit(10).pretty()
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:22Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:19Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:19Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:18Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:16Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:16Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:16Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:15Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:14Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2014-05-05T22:30:13Z") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on the field?

> Unless you have an index for the specified key pattern, use $orderby
>   in conjunction with $maxScan and/or cursor.limit() to avoid requiring
>   MongoDB to perform a large in-memory sort.

From: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

Comment: Updated the qn. But I don't think having an index should matter for this.